# Redactor stripping script/html tags

Tags: redactor, richtext

I wasn't to allow a user to enter html into the Rich Text field.

The html in question is:

```
<div class="issuuembed" style="width: 525px; height: 525px;" data-configid="7563847/30149275"></div>
<script src="//e.issuu.com/embed.js" async="true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can save the entry and on the front end the content displays ok - but when I go back in to edit the entry it is no longer there - the div and script tags have been removed.

I tried adding this

replaceDivs: false,

to the config but it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please do yourself a favor and **don't do this  in Redactor**. Find a solution with Matrix (and/or [Super Table](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable)) to add things like this in-between your text blocks.

Answer (score 3):

As you probably already know, Redactor removes any inline styling. `replaceDivs` doesn't appear to be in later versions of Redactor (at the least, it's not documented.)

Redactor will always remove Script tags, per the documentation. (I ran into this issue a few days ago.) Redactor supposedly has an option for this, but it doesn't appear to work in Craft, and has shaky documentation.

Here's the official Redactor documentation for it:

*Using this setting with false argument, you can restrict use of script tag in your HTML. Redactor will automatically and always strip this tag form the code.*

Here's the actual setting for Redactor:

`script: false`

I was able to get Redactor to allow script tags by removing that functionality from Redactor's core, but this should be considered a *very* temporary workaround until we can get someone from P&T to add it, or clarification on the tag's proper use:

1. Go to `craft/app/resources/lib/redactor/redactor.js` on line 193, and remove the 'script' tag from the array.
2. Comment out line 1980
3. Comment out line 2049
4. Comment out line 8006

Again, **this is *very* temporary until someone from P&T can confirm proper tag functionality.** You're modifying core, which is almost never a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is still an issue with Craft 3. My solution was to create a new text field for the desired section called `templateFile`. Then I edited my page template so that whenever `templateFile` is non-empty, it will `{% include block.templateFile %}` instead of the usual content.

This allows me to bypass Redactor completely while restricting any generated `<script>` tags to templates, which requires access to the server files as well as the CMS. That keeps non-admin editors from accidentally including damaging code.